# Jquery scroll top element not moving along

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the actual implemenation in the page the link is moving along with the page but not shown(visible) in page. When I click the css in browser the element appears in the scrolled position.

---

```
        //elemet to appear when scrolling
         <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        }); 

        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });

    });

    //css for the element
        .scrollup{
                    width:40px;
                    height:40px;
                    opacity:0.3;
                    position:fixed;
                    bottom:50px;
                    right:100px;
                            display:none;   
            }
```

Not working in chrome. Working in firefox.

Comment: I created a test page and tried this with Chrome25, IE9, and Firefox19. It worked fine in all three. The only thing I could suggest would be to remove `display: none;` from the style and instead initially hide the element with a call to `.hide()`.

Comment: tried that not working in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: $('body').offset().top }, 'slow' );                                     return false;   
});
```

Or

```
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $('body').scrollTop($('body')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want

js

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
});

$(".scrollup").click(function () {
   //1 second of animation time
   //html works for FFX but not Chrome
   //body works for Chrome but not FFX
   //This strange selector seems to work universally
   $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
});
```

html

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

css

```
.scrollup{
    padding: 5px 3px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px;
    display: none;
            }
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/6A6ey/1/) 
 hope this help you